# How to get the pk in generic.DetailView?

Tags: django

My `urlpatterns` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('article/<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    ...
]
```

I want to get this `pk` in the view class:

```
class ArticleDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs['pk']
```

However, this raises a KeyError:

```
KeyError at /article/2/
'pk'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `pk` in `DetailView` from `self.kwargs`. So it should be

```
class ArticleDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you're searching the value in the kwargs parameter in `get_context_data` method. You should search instead in `ArticleDetailView` kwargs like this `self.kwargs['pk']`